# NGINX LoadBalancer not working, only pulling up default index.html site on LB, not upsteam servers

Tags: nginx, tomcat, load-balancing

I setup an NGINX loadbalancer in front of 2 tomcat servers on a Cent7 system. When I try to pull them up from the LB, I just get the default index.html NGINX page from the default installation. I've gone through a bunch of guides but im not sure what im failing on. I created a load-balancer.conf file in the /etc/nginx/conf.d/ folder and it looks like this:

```
upstream backend {
  server 192.168.80.123; 
  server 192.168.80.122;
}

server {
   listen 80; 

location / {
  proxy_pass http://backend;
   }
}
```

The nginx.conf files is default right now. I followed some guides that had a setup similar to apache with sites-available, but got the same results. Seems like im missing something somewhere, but I can't find where. No matter what I try it just pulls up the default index.html file that is in /usr/share/nginx/html.

Answer (score 1):

Use `nginx -T` to test you configuration, and more importantly, view the actual configuration that `nginx` is using.

Start from `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` as all other files are included from there.

Comment: Combed back through all of the .conf and made a couple changes. I deleted my original load-balancer.conf file and recreated a default.conf file. This time i added in 'server_name tomcat-test.com' below listen port, restarted the services and it started working properly.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up deleting my `load-balancer.conf` file in the `/etc/nginx/conf.d/` folder and created a `default.conf` file. I added

```
server_name tomcat-test.com;
```

after the `listen` port in the `.conf` and restarted service. Now, its all working.

Comment: Yeah i didnt need help with the "main job" -- just needed help with the actual question I listed.  Thanks for the reply tho but kindof unnecessary.